# JSLink and office 365 : I don't see the Content Type "JavaScript Display Template" when adding js file

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jslink

I am using SharePoint Online 2013. I try to follow some JSLink tutorial to show indicators in some columns on a custom list. I am stuck in the step where I need to upload and set the ".js" file into the master page gallery. I don't see the Content Type "JavaScript Display Template". Is it because I am using SP online (office 365)? Do I need to add this ct manual? Or is it some feature which I need to enable?

http://www.abhishan.com/create-project-dashboard-with-sharepoint-2013-js-link/

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/31/uploading-javascript-js-files-as-javascript-display-template-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it should be available in O365 or not. However, you can check if it exists in Site Content Types. If it is available there, you can add it to Master page gallery List content type.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to the Master page gallery content types

Click on Library settings-->Advanced settings-->Check  Allow management of content types

Now you upload the .js file or edit the the item, you should able to see the Java Script Display template content type in drop down.